# React Component change from one type to the other

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a React component...Here's the code:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class Message extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {

    const { type } = this.props;

    if (type === 'success') {
      return (<div>{this.props.msg}</div>);
    }  
  }
}
```

I need to change it to this type of component:

```
const Message = props => (
  //Stuff here
);


export default Message
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Replace `const Message...` with `const Message = props => props.type === 'success' ? <div>{props.msg}</div> : null;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am correct, you simply want to create a stateless version of your initial component. To do this, you treat your lambda function as your render function. For example:

```
const Message = ({ type, msg }) => (type === 'success') ? <div>{msg}</div> : null
```

If you aren't comfortable with ternarys, this is the same thing as above (also with deconstruction):

```
const Message = props => {
    const { type, msg } = props
    if(type === 'success'){
        return <div>{msg}</div>
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting: Error: Message(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the else in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

Function components are basically a shorthand for a class component with only the `render` method defined. The body of the function is basically the body of the `render` function.

```
const Message = props => {
    const { type, msg } = props;

    if (type === 'success') {
      return (<div>{msg}</div>);
    }else{
        return null;
    }  // :)
};
```

Comment: Getting: Error: Message(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.